# HTTP range request for last byte

Tags: http, protocols, http-range

I'm a newbie and [I've been studying](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-latest.html) the `Range` request for byte serving. I found that a server has to send a byte-range as this

> Content-Range: bytes 734-1233/1234

for the last byte range. But how would a browser get the last byte of the file when the request itself is till the last but one byte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current standard is [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233). From [2.1 Byte Ranges](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.1):

```
The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset
of the first byte in a range.  The last-byte-pos value gives the
byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, the byte
positions specified are inclusive.  Byte offsets start at zero.
```

Applying this to the the examples in [4.2 Content-Range](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.2):

```
The following are examples of Content-Range values in which the
selected representation contains a total of 1234 bytes:

o  The first 500 bytes:

     Content-Range: bytes 0-499/1234
```

Since the range is zero-based, 0 is the first byte and 499 is the 500th. So, 1233 is the final byte of a 1234-byte document.

Comment: Thank you. So Content-Length is actual size of the file.